# How to Delete compete table from django sqlite database using django function in terminal?

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-rest-framework

I have written a code for my project, for that I have created some tables in Django SQLite database server. 
Now I want don't want table, therefore I want to remove/delete the complete table from database.
Is there any way to delete table directly from the single line of code from terminal of IDE?

I have tried using Django-admin from that I have use 'django-admin flush' and 'django-admin sqlflush' I am confuse what to use and what not to

Comment: Just delete the model in your code and run migrations

Answer (score 0):

Firstly install sqlite in your django environment using:

```
pip install sqlite3
```

Then open DB Shell on your terminal using:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

Then run this command to drop your table:

```
DROP TABLE table_name;
```

Hope this helps!